# Updating Python Class fields

Tags: python, class, dictionary, field, memory-address

This is a basic question that can shed some light on how class fields are updated. I came across the following situation:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=0
        self.my_dict={'a':self.a}

c=MyClass()
print('c.a=', c.a)
print('c.my_dict[\'a\']=', c.my_dict['a'])
c.my_dict['a']=1
print('c.a=', c.a)
print('c.my_dict[\'a\']=', c.my_dict['a'])
```

Results:

```
c.a= 0
c.my_dict['a']= 0
c.a= 0
c.my_dict['a']= 1
```

c.a has the same value. Why? Shouldn't c.a reference the same location in memory as c.my_dict['a']?

Comment: `MyClass.a` and `MyClass.my_dict` are completely independent. Changes to one do not affect the other. The source of confusion is that you use the instance's attribute `a` in the dictionary literal initializer for `my_dict` (in `__init__()`). However, using the variable name in this statement does not tie this dictionary entry's value to that attribute location in memory. Rather, all it does is evaluate the value of the attribute `a` (at that line, it is 0), and use that value to initialize the `my_dict["a"]`.

Comment: Thanks. Why is this a copy and is not referencing the same memory location?

Comment: Why would it be? `MyClass.a` is a variable that holds a value, why would evaluating that variable in an expression do anything but evaluate to its value? I updated the comment above, maybe it answers your question.

Comment: Technically, it doesn't store a copy. `self.a` evaluates to 0, then that value is stored into the dictionary. `c.my_dict['a']= 1` then changes what value is stored in the dictionary; but that doesn't affect any references to the previous value.

Comment: @Mihai.Mehe there is no copy being made. At all.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga. That part is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, after your code, you look at the variables in your class, hopefully it clarifies things:

```py
>>> vars(c)
{'a': 0, 'my_dict': {'a': 1}}
```

When you assign `self.my_dict = {'a': self.a}`, you read the current value of `a`, then make a dict `{'a': that_value}`. There is no reference to the variable `a`.

If you wanted to store such a reference, you could do something like the following:

```py
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = [0]
        self.my_dict = {'a': self.a}

c = MyClass()
>>> vars(c)
{'a': [0], 'my_dict': {'a': [0]}}

c.my_dict['a'][0] = 1
>>> vars(c)
{'a': [1], 'my_dict': {'a': [1]}}
```

Comment: This doesn't make it store a "reference" vs a "value". In Python, all values act like references anyway. The difference is that you are using an object, in this case a `list` to store the value

Comment: Interesting solution. It shows that python (specifically dict) treats type list and type int differently. All though, as they say [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/03/30/python-objects-types-classes-and-instances-a-glossary), everything in python is an object. In that regard, it should not be a difference.

Comment: Tests show the same behavior for all the primitive data types (boolean, string, integer and float) while non-primitive types I tested (dictionaries, lists, sets) give the same results as the example given above by @Pierre D.